# Enrolling a Certificate in Microsoft Certification services for a User From Java Program

Tags: java, c#, api, certificate

Using Microsft Certificate Services user can enroll/create their own certificate. How i can create this certificate using a Java Program?

Could anybody point out right apis for connecting to Microsoft certification services and do the certificate managing tasks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get information around the API [here](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/security/)

From [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/keytool.html) you can find information around keyTool which is used to generate certificates

Following commands might be of help to you

```
keytool -genkey -keystore server-keystore.jks -alias server_alias \
        -dname "CN=hostnameofserver,OU=orgunit" \
        -keyalg "RSA" -sigalg "SHA1withRSA" -keysize 2048 -validity 365

keytool -export -keystore server-keystore.jks -alias server_alias -file server.crt

keytool -import -keystore client-truststore.jks -file server.crt
```

From JDK 1.6 , you can programmatically access MS CryptoAPI also.

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/6.0-JDK-Platform/windows/sun/security/mscapi/SunMSCAPI.java.htm

Answer (score 3):

Seems JDK already had something to talk to MS Certification services. Please check out [this](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/security/#1) link. There is an example too accompanying the same link.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you will have to create [wrappers](https://github.com/twall/jna#readme) around Windows Cryptography [API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380256%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). Specifically these for [CSP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380252%28v=VS.85%29.aspx#csp_functions) provided by certadm.dll and [enroll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa382488%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) provided by xenroll.dll.

HTH