# API for Microsoft Certification Authority integration

Tags: java, ssl

Do we have a specific Java API to automate the integration with Microsoft Certification Authority (CA)?

Only the following link seems relevant, but it just provides a high level information.
[Enrolling a Certificate in Microsoft Certification services for a User From Java Program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7200823/enrolling-a-certificate-in-microsoft-certification-services-for-a-user-from-java)

Is there a way to access Microsoft Cryptography API [[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380256%28v=VS.85%29.aspx]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380256%28v=VS.85%29.aspx%5d) using Java?